# Low memory Warning Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, low-memory

All the used viewcontrollers and controls are released and deallocated upto my knowledge and Also tracked through Instrument and generic Analyzer. But my app receives low memory warning Issue.
 i have heard abt low memory warning levels.If they exists how to identify them via notification.
Meanwhile my app consumes only 16 mb RAM and works perfectly in simulator bt crashes in device.
Plz join hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low memory warnings are normal and you can't prevent them from happening because your user might be running other games at the background which is out of your control.

What you really need to care is to properly release all retained but recoverable objects and caches when you received low memory warning. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

IN below function,just comment the code

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{

     // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.

     // [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }
```

IT will solve any problem due to memory warning.Memory warnings are normal and don't need to handle them

Comment: are you sure? I think, there will be a reason why there is those method.